# Fancybox 2.1.4 alt attribute missing

Tags: jquery, attributes, fancybox, fancybox-2, alt

Sorry for my bad english, I'm French and I have a problem with the new version of Fancybox.

The alt attribute of my image is correctly inserted on my HTML but it don't appear on the HTML code of Fancybox :

```
<div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: visible; width: 521px; height: 521px;"><img alt="" src="images_produits/gigoteuse-naissance-badou-z.jpg" class="fancybox-image"></div>
```

By default the alt attribute on template of the new version is empty : alt="" (jquery.fancybox.js)
How can I fix this problem ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See `tpl` option here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ – replacing `image: '<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" />'` with `… alt="{alt}" …` should do the trick.

Comment: Tanks a lot for your answer but it doesn't work, the alt attribute appears like this on the code : alt="{alt}", another solution ?

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid you have to push the value of the `alt` attribute into the `.fancybox-image` selector.

You could get that value either from the  `alt` attribute in your `img` thumbnail like :

```
<a href="big_image.jpg" class="fancybox"><img alt="one" src="thumb_image.jpg" /></a>
```

or from a `data` attribute in your anchor like :

```
<a data-alt="alt for fancybox one" href="big_image.jpg" class="fancybox"><img alt="one" src="thumb_image.jpg" /></a>
```

then use the `beforeShow` callback to set either of them. You can give a priority to the `alt` attribute in your thumbnail or to the `data` attribute in your anchor, whatever works better for you :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        var imgAlt = $(this.element).find("img").attr("alt");
        var dataAlt = $(this.element).data("alt");
        if (imgAlt) {
            $(".fancybox-image").attr("alt", imgAlt);
        } else if (dataAlt) {
            $(".fancybox-image").attr("alt", dataAlt);
        }
    }
});
```

If none of them exists, then the `alt` of `.fancybox-image` will remain empty as in the template.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rAVCU/)**

Answer (score 0):

This code works for each selected (clicked) element, takes and adds alt attributes to images inside fancybox-content

```
jQuery('a.fancybox').fancybox({'hideOnContentClick':true,
    'titleShow':true,

    'onComplete' : function(links, index){
        var self = $(links[index]);
        var imageHtml = self[0];
        var alt = $(imageHtml).find("img").attr("alt");
        jQuery("#fancybox-wrap #fancybox-content #fancybox-img").attr('alt', alt);

    },
});
```